# Linear programming problem using the simplex algorithm, dual problem...

Tags: linear-programming

I want to maximize $z = 12x + 20y$ with the following constraints:
$$\eqalign{
  & 2x + 8y \le 180  \cr 
  & 4x + 4y \le 120  \cr 
  & x,y \ge 0 \cr} $$

I need the simplex tableau to find optimal solution but also I need to determine the dual problem and find its optimal.

Comment: There should not be 4 extra variables. $s_1, s_2$ are enough. Also the objective function is $12x+20y$. I don't think you should simplify that.

Comment: You're right, I deleted the tableau.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a detailed solution => https://i.hizliresim.com/Xqm406.png

s1 and s2 are slack variables. Cj is coefficient of the variables. In every iteration find column contains the maximum Cj-Zj and find the row of minimum ratio. Then you have a pivot at the intersection cell

The dual problem is :

minimize $ z = 180x + 120y$ due to : $$2x + 4y \ge 12$$

$$8x + 4y \ge 20$$

Edit : To calculate sensitivity of first constraint find the delegate column. The delegate of first constraint is $s1$. So get the values in column below $s1$ to get the lower bound. $$\begin{bmatrix}1/6\\-1/6\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}a&b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}20\\10\end{bmatrix}$$

Here $a$ and $b$ must be positive and we must select the minimum of the positive values $min(a,b)$. So $a = 120$ and $b = -60$. We get $a$. Then lower bound is $180 - 120 = 60$

For the upper bound :

$$\begin{bmatrix}1/6\\-1/6\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}-a&-b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}20\\10\end{bmatrix}$$

Here $a$ and $b$ must be positive too and we must select the minimum of the positive values $min(a,b)$. So $a = -120$ and $b = 60$. We get $b$. Then the upper bound is $180 + 60 = 240$

Finally we have $$ 60 \le C1 \le 240$$

Comment: Thank you so much. How do I determine how much I can change 180 or 120 by without it affecting the result?

Comment: I have updated my answer.Take a look But you can find more detalied answers in google.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the following tableau:
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
x&y&s_1&s_2&z&RHS\\
1&4&1&0&0&90\\
1&1&0&1&0&30\\
-12&-20&0&0&1&0
\end{array}